# Transfer electron renderer process to default browser

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to switch my electron app to the browser tab. Is it possible to do so like switching the renderer process to the default browser and communicate with the electron main process?

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response, couldn't find any workaround

Comment: The only way I found is to create a server in the localhost from the electron side and communicate it from there

Comment: It works using localhost.

Comment: You mean you are interacting with the browser app form Electron?